# Microsoft Advertisement SDK for Windows Phone 8: Demo ad not showing due to error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, ads

Yet another "I can't get the ads to work"-post :-)

- It's a Windows Phone 7.x project that has been ported to a Visual Studio 2013 project.
- All the necessary Capabilites are added to the WMAppManifest.xml, so that is no issue.
- I drag/dropped the AdControl onto the page so the default values for the test ad are inserted. But no visual is shown in designer mode
- An error is thrown when running the app. Catching the error gives me the following result:

> [InnerException]
>        System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
>        [System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebResponse]
>        https://mobileads-test.msn.com/v3/Delivery/Placement?pubid=test_client&pid=Image480_80&adm=2&cfmt=text,image,html5richmedia,polyad&pm=1&sft=jpeg,png,gif&w=480&h=80&fmt=json&cltp=app&dim=le&rafb=0&nct=1&lc=en-US&idtp=mid&uid=055bc3a4-8891-4189-ae3d-b644538d3e8c&aid=e16448ed-181c-4775-a889-fced00b7c636&devmake=Microsoft&devmodel=XDeviceEmulator&devos=Windows%20Phone&devosver=8.0.9903.0&devosid=202&asid=6d2d2ce01f8c47db8e92c7bd19435dea

Also,

I released a version of my app on the store and it got accepted, offcourse using the correct AppId's and so on in the AdControl. I can see entries in the Microsoft pubCenter since a couple of days, but when I launch the app myself I can't see any advertisement showing on the screen, Just a black square box.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So there is a new ad SDK that you need to use. It comes with WP8 vs13 and I am guessing by dragging and dropping the ad control onto the page you implemented it. That said, do some research and make sure that you are not implementing the old ad SDK. implementing both will cause this issue. You should only have 1 reference to advertising in your project

Comment: I've found that occasionally things temporality don't work, after a while they start to work again.  But, I haven't seen that specific error.

Comment: I've been told that Bing Ads has about a 60% hit rate (meaning about 40% of the time it doesn't have an ad).  So the common practice is to fall back to another ad provider when things like this happen.